# NHibernate Restriction.IN doesn't work with IList

Tags: nhibernate, ilist

We are using NHibernate.  Have 2 Classes Parent class which contains IList of Child Classes.

From the table I have to get all the Parents that have certain Child elemnts.  My code is as follows:

```
String[] childs= { "Child1", "Child2" };
ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(**Parent**));
criteria.Add(Restrictions.In("Roles", **childs**));
return criteria.List<Parent>() as List<Parent>;
```

***This is throwing "NHibernate.QueryException : Cannot use collections with InExpression" Error.***

Can someone please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot use collections with InExpression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283989/cannot-use-collections-with-inexpression)

Answer (score 2):

I believe here is your answer you need add alias to child [Cannot use collections with InExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283989/cannot-use-collections-with-inexpression)

Comment: flag as duplicate, no need to answer